# Keyboard input doesn't work in various snap apps after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: keyboard, snap, input

After the update I noticed that I can't type in firefox.

After changing the snap for the ppa from mozilla the problem was solved. But then I noticed that typing also doesn't work in signal-desktop installed as snap and the snap-store.

So i'd like to address the root of the problem but don't know where to start.

[edit]
So as I said I can't type in firefox or signal and I'll add to that mailspring.
In the snap store, if I type, only one letter appears in the search bar and then the keyboad stops working.

Shortcuts only work if no text input is selected
Right click/menu paste does work.

But in phpstorm typing (everything) works as expected.

As mentioned this only happens in snap applications, the rest of the system is fine.

Comment: You cannot type *at all* or only in certain circumstances? Provide detailed steps so someone else can reproduce your actions and see if the problem is reproduced. Use "edit" to add any relevant info to your question.

Comment: Steps to reproduce is just simple. Install snap try to type in it, fail. This only happened after the upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04.

Comment: It is always wise to specify a precise procedure that allows one to reproduce the issue. Still some other tips for you to debug: 1) temporarily create a new acccount - check if issue in the new account 2) log in on Xorg - check if issue is there

Comment: I have the same problem. However, this does not happen _always_. It happens on some times that I have not been able to determine. If, after a launch of Firefox the keyboard does not work, I have no other way than to close Firefox, wait a bit until all _firefox_ processes exit, and then restart Firefox. Most of the cases, the keyboard will work after the restart.

Comment: Same problem here, just updated to Ubuntu 23.04 (from 22.04)

Answer (score 3):

For Firefox, I found a way to remove the snap version and to install and maintain the .deb version.  It may be possible for other snaps, though I have not explored it.

The procedure is documented here:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

The linked-to page uses echo and tee to create two new text files.  Below is my paraphrase using my favorite text editor.  Prefix the commands below with sudo if your user privilege level requires it.

Remove the Firefox snap:

```
snap remove firefox
```

Add the Mozilla repository:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

The following two files do not exist.  You create them in your favorite text editor.

Switch to the .deb version:

File /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Set it up for automatic updades:

File /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";
```

Install the .deb version.
apt install firefox

Use the software launcher to pin Firefox to the dock if desired.